# Javascript -How can I convert DDMMYYYY to format (YYYY-MM-DD)?

Tags: javascript, typescript, date, sequelize.js

In my project I have PostgreSql table which contain `date` (Data type date)column. The date received from column is being passed to getData function.

I am getting output in format `03122021`, which I want to convert in format `2021-12-03` (YYYY-MM-DD) `DATE ONLY`. How can I make the conversion?

```
 async getData(date){
         console.log("date is ", date);     ---->>> date is 03122021
        const d = new Date(Date.parse(date));
        console.log('d', d)                  ---->> d Invalid Date
    }
```

Comment: The use of *Date.parse* in `new Date(Date.parse(date))` is redundant. Also note that `new Date('2021-12-03')` will be parsed as UTC, see [*Why does Date.parse give incorrect results?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/why-does-date-parse-give-incorrect-results)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So parse the sting into a format it recognizes

```js
const date = '03122021'
const d = new Date(date.replace(/(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{4})/,'$2/$1/$3'));
console.log(d);


const d2 = date.replace(/(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{4})/,'$3-$2-$1');
console.log(d2);
```

Comment: Thanks, but I just need `date 2021-12-03`, no timestamp. Can you help me with that? –

Comment: so just format it without a date.... change the replace line

Answer (score 0):

You could convert the date in your sql query:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(dateColumn, 'yyyy-mm-dd') AS formattedDate FROM ...
```

Comment: Hi this is the query I am using `return (await this._permanent.findAll({ where: { data_date:date } })).map((term) => ({}}` Where can I add here? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not perfect answer but if you get this type of value alltime , then you can do this

```
const dateValue = '03122021'
let day = dateValue.substring(0,2)
let month = dateValue.substring(2,4)
let year = dateValue.substring(4,8)
const date =`${year}-${month}-${day}`
console.log(date)
```